# subscript out of bounds error in R programming

Tags: r, facebook, stringindexoutofbounds

Getting following error while using `prophet` library:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, m$history$t >= m$changepoints.t[i], i, value =
>   1) : subscript out of bounds

Code : `m <- prophet(data)` this data I've loaded from csv file.

My dataset looks like this :

```
                   ds        y 
1 2017-05-23 08:07:00 21.16641
2 2017-05-23 08:07:10 16.79345
3 2017-05-23 08:07:20 16.40846
4 2017-05-23 08:07:30 16.24653
5 2017-05-23 08:07:40 16.14694
6 2017-05-23 08:07:50 15.89552
```

`ds` column is of following type :`"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` 
 `y` column is of following type :`"numeric"` (these are log values of some count values)

Being new to R, i don't have any clue on how to resolve this. Please help.

Comment: @marco, can you give any clues for my question?

Comment: @MarcoSandri please format it I dont know how to do.

Comment: @MarcoSandri any hints?

Comment: @marcosandri , any suggestions you can give further?

Comment: Try with the python `prophet` library.

Comment: See `?prophet`, the `ds` variable needs to be a Date class (not POSIXct). This works (but is of course fake): `data$ds <- seq.Date(as.Date("2016-1-1"),as.Date("2016-1-6"), by="1 day")` and then run `prophet(data)`

Comment: @RemkoDuursma, I am facing the same problem, but my ```ds``` variable is a ```Date```. Any other suggestion?

Comment: No I don't - can you post a reproducible problem (with some made-up data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data does not have any change points (points of interest in your data series where there is change in the local trend direction). This error seems like a bug in the Prophet package which is not handling this situation gracefully. However you can fix this by setting the changepoint tuning parameters.

Quick fix: set changespoints to 0 by using param:

```
n.changepoints = 0
```

in your prophet call.